# jQuery Mobile, allowSamePageTransition can't transition to same page more than once

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app using jQuery Mobile.  The page I'm working on loads content from server and updates the DOM before transitioning to that page.

While this is not the app, I've isolated the problem in this simplistic page removing all ajax calls an all other javascript and html: [Simplstic page](http://sources.featsoflife.com/test.html)

**The desired behaviour**: it should load page 2 and then upon clicking the link on page 2 transition to page 2 again and again.  This is what the allowSamePageTransition property is for if I'm not mistaken.

**The way it actually behaves**: The link on page 1 transitions to page 2, then the link on page 2 transitions to page 2 again, but then I can't click on anything, the element on top seems to be the body.

I've set the page up so you can just copy the source into an editior and try it out without modifying any links.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug, if I've missed something in the docs, please point it out to me.  I've gotten this kind of mechanism to work before but right now I can't figure out why the simpest example won't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same Page Transitions are not fully supported. I have had good luck with "A" & "B" pages that are identical and then transition back and forth between them.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

Using same page transition

Transitions to the current active page are ignored by default but can be enabled by using the allowSamePageTransition option of the $.mobile.changePage method. **Note that not all transitions will work as expected and may end in an impractical result.**

Comment: *sigh* I went with the cycling between multiple pages option, was probably a better option to preload content for all pages anyways...