# JQuery pagecontainer change on same page locks up

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using Cordova 6.1.1, JQuery 2.1.4, and JQueryMobile 1.4.5.  If I am already on main.html and change pages to main.html the page locks up and nothing becomes clickable.  Can someone tell me why that is?  I am using the code below to change pages.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My App" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainPage" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
                <button id="logout" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Logout</button>              
                <h1>Header 1</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <div id="current"></div>                
                <button id="button1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all top-margin-1-5">Button 1</button>
                <button id="button2" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all top-margin-1-5">Button 2</button>
                <button id="button3" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all top-margin-1-5">Button 3</button>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->    
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#mainPage", function() {
    var $mainPage = $("#mainPage");
    var $button1 = $("#button1", $mainPage);        
    var $button2 = $("#button2", $mainPage);
    var $button3 = $("#button3", $mainPage);
    var $logout = $("#logout", $mainPage);

    $logout.off("click").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do something
    });

    $button1.off("click").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "main.html", {reload: true}); // locks up page            
    });

    $button2.off("click").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "main.html", {allowSamePageTransition: true}); // doesn't lock up page
    });

    $button3.off("click").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do something
    });
});
```

CSS

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    color:#0071bc;
}
/* Change border radius of icon buttons */
.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-corner-all {
    -webkit-border-radius: .3125em;
    border-radius: .3125em;
}
/* Change color of JQuery Mobile page headers */
.ui-title {
    color:#fff;
}
/* Center-aligned text */
.text-center {
    text-align:center;
}
/* Top margin for some elements */
.top-margin-1-5 {
    margin-top:1.5em;
}
h2.text-danger,
h3.text-danger  {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: The code that you've posted should work. I have made a mini-demonstration on pagecontainer change [here](https://www.elitesystemer.no/demo/test/36459671/index.html), that might be of help. Otherwise, you'll need to post more code.

Comment: Does setting allowSamePageTransition: true help?

Comment: Using allowSamePageTransition did help.  It loaded the page without locking it up, however when I went back to using reload it did lock it up.  It is also worth noting that using reload doesn't lock it up on every page.  I'll paste more source code in the hopes someone can help me figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I just found an older post with someone having the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053601/jquery-mobile-allowsamepagetransition-cant-transition-to-same-page-more-than-o)... is it safe to just change all reload: true to allowSamePageTransition: true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up changing all the reload calls to be allowSamePageTransition instead.